# How to pass session attribute to a ThymeLeaf form field for saving into database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf form that sends data to a database table when the user is logged in. The ThymeLeaf template is able to capture the session of the logged in user from it's assigned controller. When saving data to the database.

I need to accompany the form data alongside the captured session username, such that the said session username is saved in the database table as well. However I get an error that says

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'userName' of bean class
>   [com.example.jobonics.Persistence.model.NewJobs]: Bean property
>   'userName' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the
>   return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

I have a controller that picks the user session and sends it to the thymeleaf template as well as a hidden input user field in my form that holds the session object from the controller. My code is pasted below for some clarity:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new_job", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newRegistration(ModelMap model) {
    NewJobs newJobs = new NewJobs();
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes)
    RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

   //extract user session from HttpSession
    HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession(true);
    //initialize user service to get authenticated user
    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());

    model.addAttribute("newjobs", newJobs);
    //add session captured name as attribute to view
    model.addAttribute("userName", "Welcome " + user.getFullName() + "");
    return "new_job";

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveRegistration(@Valid NewJobs newJobs, BindingResult result, 
ModelMap model,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
     System.out.println("has errors");
        return "new_job";
    }

    NJS.save(newJobs);


    return "redirect:/new_job";
}
}
```

My controller

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${newjobs}" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:value="*{userName}" style="display:none">
    </div>
</div>
```

NewJobs

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "newjobs")
public class NewJobs {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int job_id;

@Column(name = "Employer")
private String Employer;

@Column(name = "JobTitle")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide the job title")
private String jobTitle;

@Column(name = "job_summary", length = 1000)
private String jobSummary;

@Column(name = "job_description", length = 1000)
private String jobDescription;

@Column(name = "location")
private String Location;

@Column(name = "career_level")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide career level required")
private String careerLevel;

@Column(name = "industry")
private String industry;

@Column(name = "profession")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide the profession")
private String profession;

@Column(name = "jobtype")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide your job type")

private String jobType;
@Column(name = "min_experience")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide the Min years of experience")

private String minExperience;
@Column(name = "min_qualification")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide the Min Qualifications")
private String minQualification;

@Column(name = "salary")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide the salary")
private String salary;

@Column(name = "deadline_date")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide the Applications Deadline")
private String deadlineDate;

@Column(name = "created_at", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", insertable = false, nullable = false)
private Date created_at;
}`
```

My expected output is to send the logged in user session object to db as part of a submitted form. What can I do to correct the said error above?

Comment: Can you post the code for the `NewJobs ` class?

Comment: @AK47 check the updated question with the NewJobs class

Comment: check my answer

Comment: It didn't work. I set up getter/setter methods to represent `userName`, but the value that is sent to the database table shows NULL

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value for `user.getFullName()` to see what the value is before you add it to the model? Is it empty ?

Comment: Yes, I am modelling a NewJobs object. The NewJobs table has a column for userName. The userName value in the form is captured from the session of the logged in user. It's this value that I need to save to the database table from the form but it shows NULL. `user.getFullName()` prints the value of a logged in user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188546/discussion-between-connoisseur-and-ak47).

Comment: th:field=''userName" will resolve your issue

Comment: @soorapadman the form gets submitted but specific column for `userName` in database displays NULL instead of the actual data.

Comment: @connoisseur I understood in order to get the value while submitting we should use `th:field`

Comment: @soorapadman The `userName` field in the form already contains a captured session value of the logged in user. I've placed it in a text field such that it goes to the db when form is submitted but still shows null.

Comment: @connoisseur yes you have captured but not assigned to `newJobs` object. You got me ?. It just showing not setting to your `newjobs` object

Comment: Got you now. Please guide me on how I can assign it to my `newJobs` object.

Comment: try this `<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{userName}"  th:value="*{userName}" style="display:none">` I believe newJobs has a property `userName` with the getter setter

Comment: @soorapadman Should I also make any modifications to my action save controller? The error `java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 user cannot be resolved to a variable` is being thrown

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is you got username from wrong location:
`th:value="*{userName}"` mean `newjobs.username`
but in controller, you do not set username to `newjobs`, you set to model attribute

Let change code in controller (with additional getter)
`newjobs.setUserName("Welcome " + user.getFullName())`

or
`th:value="${userName}"` (`$` but not `*`)

Note:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax

> There is an important difference though: the asterisk syntax evaluates
>   expressions on *selected objects* rather than on the whole context. That
>   is, as long as there is no selected object, the dollar and the
>   asterisk syntaxes do exactly the same.

Comment: Doesn't work. The form submits a null value to the database table.

Comment: Form can not submit value to database table directly. It submit data to an (POST) action in controller. Here i think it should posted valid data to controller. Can you show me your action which handle POST form, and how you save data to database?

Comment: check my updated code block with action save in controller

Comment: `newJobs` in your `save` action does not contains `userName` (your NewJobs entity does not have userName property). You need to add `userName` property to `newJobs` or send addtional parameter to `NJS.save`, such as `NJS.save(newJobs, userName)` where userName get from the session

Comment: Still doesn't work as the `userName` `cannot be resolved to variable`